# Sorting and grouping data from an Array

Tags: angular, sorting, grouping

I have an array of data named history and the data inside of it is sorted and ordered by day of creation. I would like, in addition to the data beeing sorted by day display the elements created

I would like to add the "created in the last hour" group

Comment: what have you tried so far?

Comment: I don't really know where to start to be honest because at first I didn't know how to group the elements by day so that took a lot of my time.

Answer (score 0):

As your date is a string formatting in a "standar format" you can use reduce without transform de date string to a Date. Futhermore, you can create directly an array in reduce

```
  groupByDate(data)
  {
    const now=new Date().getTime()
    return data.reduce((a:any,b:any)=>{
      const date=b.date.split('T')[0]
      const el=a.find(x=>x.date==date)

      //b.date becomes to be an object of type Date
      b.date=new Date(b.date)

      //you can add a new Property to "b"
      b.inLastHour=(now-b.date.getTime())<(1000*60*60)

      if (el)
      {
        el.data.push(b)

        //when add an element, sort the "data"
        el.data.sort((a,b)=>a.date.getTime()-b.date.getTime())
      }
      else
        a.push({date:date,data:[b]})
      return a
    },[])
  }
```

Now you can write, e.g.

```
<label><input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="only" />Only in the last hour</label>
<ng-container *ngFor="let item of dataOrdered">
  <h1>{{ item.date }}</h1>
  <ng-container class="item" *ngFor="let dat of item.data">
    <div class="item" *ngIf="!only || dat.inLastHour">
      <span>{{ dat.SNS }}</span>
      <span>{{ dat.title }}</span>
      <span>{{ dat.DMC }}</span>
      <span>{{ dat.date | date: 'yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm' }}</span>
      <span>{{ dat.showTrash }}</span>
      <span>{{ dat.points }}</span>
      <span>{{ dat.id }}</span>
      <span>{{ dat.inLastHour }}</span>
    </div>
  </ng-container>
</ng-container>
```

See [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-h828ib?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

NOTE: Really I whould prefer use a function and two variables instead use a pipe transform

**Update**

We add a variable "inLastHour" to the elements of the array "data". We can add a new variable "someInLastHour" to the elements in array dataOrdered

```
  if (el)
  {
    //we check the value of someInLastHour
    el.someInLastHour=el.someInLastHour || b.inLastHour

    el.data.push(b)
    el.data.sort((a,b)=>a.date.getTime()-b.date.getTime())
  }
  else
  {
    //add a property "someInLastHour"
    a.push({date:date,someInLastHour:b.inLastHour,data:[b]})
  }
```

Now, we can use this variable to show or not the element

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let item of dataOrdered">
  <div *ngIf="!only || item.someInLastHour">
    <h1>{{ item.date }}</h1>
    ....
  </div>
</ng-container>
```

**Update 2**

If only want the elements that fullfilled the condition we can create a function like

```
  groupByDateOnlyLastHour(data,now)
  {
    return data.reduce((a:any,b:any)=>{
      const date=b.date.split('T')[0]
      const el=a.find(x=>x.date==date)

      //b.date becomes to be an object of type Date
      b.date=new Date(b.date)

      //we check if fullfilled condition
      const inLastHour=(now-b.date.getTime())<(1000*60*60)
      if (inLastHour){ //we add
         if (el)
         {
           el.data.push(b)

           //when add an element, sort the "data"
           el.data.sort((a,b)=>a.date.getTime()-b.date.getTime())
         }
         else
           a.push({date:date,data:[b]})
      return a
    },[])
    .filter(x=>x.data.length) //<--finally filter
  }
```

Comment: Thank you this helped a lot I am now able to display the elements created in the last hour. However do you know how I can only display them if they exist : I am guessing with *ngIf but what is it equal to ?

Comment: @YoussefKharoufi, I update the answer (and the stackblitz) to add a new property "someInLastHour". If we only add to the "dataOrdered" the elements that fullfilled the condition, we could use some like `*ngIf="item.data.length"`, as we add all the elements we need add a new variable. Another option could be create a function that check is some of the elements in "item.data" fullfilled the condition, but in general is a bad idea (offer a poor performance) write a function in the .html -it's called several time-.

Comment: Thanks a lot it works. Just one last thing : I am writing "Last Hour" in my component and I would like to show it only if there are elements that are from the last hour. Do you know how I could do it ?

Comment: So... is it possible ?

Comment: Just use a variable `this.some=this.items.find(x=>x.someInLastHour)?true:false` NOTE: In all the e.g. I "play" to allow show the last hour items or not using a checkBox. If only do you want to show always the lastHour we can make that "items" only have elements of the data that fullfilled the condition (see the update answer)