# How can make data results groupBy, orderBy and take with use RxJS and get date from RxJS store?

Tags: angular, rxjs

Can you help me write a query I need? I need to groupBy(smileTypeId) and row countBy(id) where postId orderBy(count) desc take(2).

Get Smiles array from RxJS store

[Display Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TVLi5.jpg)

[Get Post Smiles](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xuhr4.jpg)

```
  posts = [
    { "smileTypeId": 100000, "postId": 100068, "id": 100403 },
    { "smileTypeId": 100001, "postId": 100046, "id": 100404 },
    { "smileTypeId": 100004, "postId": 100068, "id": 100405 },
    { "smileTypeId": 100000, "postId": 100025, "id": 100406 },
    { "smileTypeId": 100003, "postId": 100006, "id": 100407 },
    { "smileTypeId": 100001, "postId": 100068, "id": 100408 },
    { "smileTypeId": 100000, "postId": 100067, "id": 100409 },
    { "smileTypeId": 100003, "postId": 100068, "id": 100410 },
    { "smileTypeId": 100005, "postId": 100056, "id": 100411 },
    .
    .
    .
  ]
```

Example result:

| SmileTypeId | Count |
| --- | --- |
| 100005 | 36 |
| 100002 | 25 |

Comment: In general the only it's use map rxjs operator and work with the response using forEach or reduce method of arrays

Comment: Can you share a sample code ?

Comment: ::glups:: really in rxjs you can use group, see, e.g. this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51841608/when-to-use-rxjs-observableobject-and-observableobject/51848901#51848901). [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72863290/sorting-and-grouping-data-from-an-array/72865344#72865344) you have an example of groupby "in pure javascript"

Comment: @Eliseo sorry man, I couldn't do it, I'm still very new to rxjs.

Answer (score 0):

```
  getSmilesCountByPostId(id: number) {
let pSmilesCount: { smileTypeId: Number, count: Number }[] = [];

if (this.pSmiles.filter(item => item.postId === id).length > 0) {
  const pSmiles = this.pSmiles.filter(item => item.postId === id).reduce((count, current) => (count[current.smileTypeId] = count[current.smileTypeId] + 1 || 1, count), []);

  Object.entries(pSmiles).forEach(item => pSmilesCount.push({ smileTypeId: Number(item[0]), count: item[1] }));

  pSmilesCount.sort((a, b) => (a.count > b.count) ? -1 : ((b.count > a.count) ? 1 : 0));
}

return pSmilesCount;
```

}

I found such a solution, I will continue with this for now

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).